# Grizzly, instance launched OK but no console output

Tags: openstack

I am running Grizzly on a two node configuration. If I use the standard images, I.e. cirros-0.3.0-x86_64-disk.img or any of the ubuntu-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img I have no problems, console log is there. But if I create an image using KVM and any of the ubuntu ISO standard files, then I don't get a console log. Instances always run OK and I can access them via the dashboard login screen, and there are no error messages about the console; console.log is always 0 bytes on these cases. Is there any difference on those cloud images that I need to add to my image creation process? I have already tried and added libvirt unsuccessfully.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Thank you @Lorin Hochstein， May I ask another question? If I use windows image, like XP, 2008. Then, how can I get a console log file like linux OS?

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

1. Inside of your virtual machine, edit `/etc/default/grub` so it has the line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0"
   ```
2. Do

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

### Longer answer

Grub needs to be configured to write the boot messages to the serial device (ttyS0). In particular, on Ubuntu, in your /boot/grub/grub.cfg, there should be a line that has `console=ttyS0`, like this:

```
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-virtual root=UUID=6d2231e4-0975-4f35-a94f-56738c1a8150 ro console=ttyS0
```

However, you shouldn't edit this file directly. Instead, you should edit `/etc/default/grub` to specify the additional parameters to be passed to the kernel  and then run `update-grub`, which will update the files in /boot/grub for you. Specify the `console=ttyS0` argument by editing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable defined in `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: Thank you @Lorin Hochstein， May I ask another question? If I use windows image, like XP, 2008. Then, how can I get a console log file like linux OS?

Comment: @BigTiger I suggest you ask this as a separate question, either on ask.openstack.org or on serverfault.com.